# Submit not inserting data?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use AJAX to submit my form, but the data isn't being passed. However, I receive a success message.

Do I need to somehow specify my variables in my data string?

```
var dataString = first_name + surname + email_addr + user_age + user_type;
//alert (dataString);return false;

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "process-signup.php",
  data: dataString,
  success: function() {
    $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
       $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")
    .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")
    .hide()
    .fadeIn(1500, function() {
      $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/check.png' />");
    });
  }
 });
return false;
```

Comment: Can you post at least the function declaration in PHP code?

Comment: Yes of course you need the parameter names in the string - how else could your server possibly know how to interpret that blob of values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep. Either pass a json like:

```
JSON.stringify({ firstName: first_name, surName: surname ... });
```

As pointed out in the comments if you're using jQuery ajax, it will automatically convert objects into query string.

or specify the parameter names (you are only passing a string, a valid query string should look like 'parametername1=paramatervalue1&parametername2=paramatervalue2'):

```
data: 'firstName=' + first_name + '&surname=' + surname + '&email=' + email_addr ...
```

Then on server side you should have variables like:

```
$_POST['firstName']; // first_name
$_POST['surname']; // surname
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: If one passes an object to `$.ajax()`, then jQuery will do the "stringify" work.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "process-signup.php",
  data: {Firstname:first_name,Surname:surname,Email:email_addr,Age:user_age,User_type:user_type},
  success: function() {
    $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
       $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")
    .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")
    .hide()
    .fadeIn(1500, function() {
      $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/check.png' />");
    });
  }
 });

 return false;
```

In server side use `$_POST['Firstname']`,`$_POST['Surname']` etc to obtain the passed value.

Answer (score 0):

Im a little bit rusty on PHP, but you are POSTing but you are sending a dataString. Usually, you use a GET request with a dataString. Additionally, the datastring usually looks like this:

var dataString = 'first_name='+first_name + '&surname='+ surname + '&email_addr=' + email_addr + '&user_age=' + user_age + '&user_type=' + user_type;

Additionally, when you use $.ajax, the success function has a parameter, data, which is usually returned from the php script when you echo.

So it would be written like this:

```
  success: function(data) {
    console.log('i got data!',data);
  }
```